# Efficient way to work with large array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large-ish array of around 500 integer values. I have another integer, which I need to test against each of the values in the array to see if it meets the condition of being between the array value - 15 and the array value + 15. Other than just iterating through each value in the array and doing the comparison, is there a neater, more efficient way to do this? I'm using PHP 5.2

EDIT: So if i have array(10,...,2500) and $n = 2510, I want to see if $n matches the condition of being between 15 either side of any of the array values. In this case, the condition would be true for the last value, 2500.

I realise 500 isn't exactly a monstrous array :)

Comment: Do you want to have all those values, that meet the condition, or do you want to know, whether your single value meets the condition at least once for some element inside the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [following snippet](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KcS3p2) will return the values between n-15 to n+15 in the array on my run-of-the-mill desktop in less than 0.001 seconds (and that includes generating the array with values to search for):

```
$n = 2500;
print_r(
    array_filter(
        array_map(function($v) {return $v * 10;}, range(1,500)),
        function($v) use ($n) {
            return $v > $n-15 && $v < $n+15;
        }
    )
);
```

I understood you are using PHP5.2 and cannot use the exact snippet above due to the Closure and Lambda, but that's not the point (just use regular functions for the callbacks). The point is, if less than 0 seconds for 500 array values is not good enough in the overall scope of your application, then go ahead and write an algorithm in userland. But if less than 0 seconds is fine, then dont try to outsmart PHP.

Comment: if it takes less than 0 seconds, then that indeed is mighty impressive :)

Comment: @Sam feel free to profile the code on your machine. 500 array values really isnt much. IMO, it's completely overkill to implement a userland binary search to achieve what the OP asks for.

Comment: I appreciate that.  It was a tongue in cheek comment about the 'takes less than zero seconds'.  Unless you have some time travelling machine, nothing takes less than 0 seconds.  Apologies if you misunderstood and took it the wrong way.  Binary search may very well be overkill here, but the op asked for a more efficient way of doing it, and given his array is already sorted, a binary search is more efficient.  The knowledge gained will hopefully aid him in the future, if say his array expands to 1 million elements. Who is to say the code is not being run in a tight loop?

Comment: @Sam No worries. No offense taken. I agree that there might be more efficient approaches to the problem in theory. I'm just not approaching the OP's question from that academic angle, but from a pragmatic POV. Yes, the numbers will likely change given other conditions, but that's why I suggested to profile the code in the context of the OP's application to see if it performs good enough. Basically, what I was trying to say was: dont optimize if you dont have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make this more efficient if you add some more information into the mix, by sorting the array or similar.  otherwise you can only compare every value.  but 500 is not a lot.

if you sort the array then you could improve performance in several ways, like looking at each value to see if it is within the range and stopping when you find the first one that is not (small improvement probably).  Or you could search for the first element which is in range and the first element which is out of range and then you know the indices of the valid elements and can just use those.

you could find the indices of interest using a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)  which will be quicker than looking at each value.

Obviously the benefits of doing this depend on the context, as phant0m pointed out in the comments, if you are going to sort the array once for each comparison, then you may as well not bother, and just do the comparison.  If you are going to look in the same array for many different comparison values then sorting may benefit you.  If you can create the array already sorted at no extra cost, then its a win-win situation.

a binary search over an array of 500 elements will take about 8 searches.  If you only need to find if one of the values matches your condition or not then this will be much more efficient.  if you need to find all the values which do, then you'll need to do a bit of modification to find the first value which is within it and the last, but it should still come out at <25 comparisons rather than 250 (average comparisons of your sorted array doing it sequentially).  but the benefits will be more noticable the bigger the array, as there will be some overhead in working out the next search point etc...

[Here is an example of binary search in PHP](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phparray/binarysearch.html), this is just a google result, not checkd or verified by me, and will need tweaking to allow for your range condition.

[this one](http://terenceyim.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/all-purpose-binary-search-in-php/) might be better and might allow you to provide a comparer which will test for the range you want.

Comment: Sorting? For heavens no. When you sort, you need to look at each element at least once, you can just run your compare function directly then. You might argue, that the sorting function is not in PHP, and that's why it is faster. But even if, you will still need to go search manually through the array to find those values you're interested in.

Comment: @phant0m, that depends on if you are going to be doing the compare many times on the same array.  then it may be more efficient to sort first.  Or the OP may be able to create the array in a sorted way in the first place at no extra cost.  I'm only trying to say that without doing something else there is no more efficient way that testing every value, as you don't know anything else about any of the values.  With some extra info it is possible to do it more efficiently.  whether generating that extra info is worth the cost, well that's a contextual judgement call.

Comment: Agreed. I thought you meant to take the array, sort it, and then go search for the values.

Comment: the array is always sorted in ascending order

Comment: @callumb, then you are in luck.  see edit.  binary search is probably your friend.

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing searches and adds ad hoc then use a tree as follows

put the numbers in a tree instead of an array. then use binary search to find where your new item is in the array. then check to see if it's within 15 of the previous and next items in the array.

now instead of around count($thearray) operations. it's log(count($thearray)) operations.

so that's more efficient.

if you have the data and are going to just be doing searches, then use an ordered array, and do a bsearch of that array and just check the previous and next.

Answer (score 0):

It *may* be quicker to use PHP's built-in functions:

```
$arr1 = range(10,2500);
$n = 2510;
$arr2 = range($n - 15, $n + 15);
print_r(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [2485] => 2495
    [2486] => 2496
    [2487] => 2497
    [2488] => 2498
    [2489] => 2499
    [2490] => 2500
)
```

Comment: takes ~0.002s on my desktop. still likely good enough for the OPs needs.

Comment: @Gordon: I didn't time it, but it seemed pretty quick.  Out of curiosity, did you time it with the same range as yours?

Comment: @Mike yes. I used this code http://codepad.viper-7.com/m12rmm. When I use your code, it performs somewhat worse. Probably because there is more values to intersect from. But these numbers are meaningless anyway when not put into context of a full application.

Comment: @Gordon: Yes, creating the extra array just to use `array_intersect` is quite wasteful.  I'd not seen codepad before - that'll come in handy.

Comment: @Mike - your approach applies the range to $n, the range should in fact be applied to each of the array values. The aim is to check if $n is within -15 and +15 of any of the range values

Comment: @callum: My method creates a range that is $n ±15.  It then compares each value in the array to each value in the ±15 range. $n ±15 is a range, after all.  It only works with integers of course, and Gordon's method is faster and more efficient.